# Camera controls are opposite to what they should be. Why?

Tags: graphics, three.js, camera, axis

I am creating a playable maze in Three.js. All the objects —the floor, the ceiling and the walls— have been placed within positive X and Z axises. The camera is placed like this:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,
                                         window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
                                         0.1,
                                         1000
    );
    camera.position.set(0, 0.25, 0);

    // The camera is placed pointing to the nearest open path from the
    // initial position. Check mazeGenerator.js for the reference of
    // "coordinates".
    if(grid[1][0] == coordinates.W)
    {
        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0.25, 0));
    }
    else
    {
        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0.25, 1));
    }
```

and it moves like that:

```
function keyboardCheck()
{
    var movementSpeed = 0.02;
    var rotationSpeed = 0.03;

    if(keyboard.pressed('w') || keyboard.pressed('up'))
    {
        camera.translateZ(-movementSpeed);
    }

    if(keyboard.pressed('a') || keyboard.pressed('left'))
    {
        camera.rotateY(rotationSpeed);
    }

    if(keyboard.pressed('d') || keyboard.pressed('right'))
    {
        camera.rotateY(-rotationSpeed);
    }
}
```

If I place the camera without the `lookAt` function, it seems that it faces `[0, 0, 0]`, but of course what I wanted to do was help the player a little bit by making the camera face the nearest open path possible.

In order to make it move forward, I have to decrement Z, because otherwise when you hit the "move forward" key it goes backwards. This makes me think that even though I am telling the camera to look at a certain direction, the object's Z axis is opposite to the world's Z axis.

The question itself is: why is this happening?

Thank you very much in advance.

- https://github.com/MikelAlejoBR/3D-Maze-95/tree/0.4
- https://github.com/MikelAlejoBR/3D-Maze-95/issues/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera is looking down its negative-z axis, so to move forward, do this:

```
camera.translateZ( - distance );
```

All other objects are considered to be looking in the direction of their positive-z axis, so to move other objects forward, you would use

```
object.translateZ( distance );
```

three.js r.85